# Convergence of subsets defined by measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $2^X$ denote the set of all subsets of $X$. Given two subsets $A,B\subseteq X$, we define the distance $d(A,B)=\mu^*((A-B)\cup (B-A))$, where $\mu^*$ is the outer measure.
>
> Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots\subseteq X$ be such that for some $\varepsilon$, for all $n$, if $i>j>n$ then $d(A_i,A_j)<\varepsilon^n$. Let $B=\bigcap_{l=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{j\geq l}A_j$. Prove that the sequence $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ converges to $B$.

So the sequence $A_i$ is a Cauchy sequence, and it converges geometrically. Since we must prove that $A_1,A_2,\ldots $ converges to $B$, I looked at the difference $d(A_i,B)=\mu^*((A_i-B)\cup(B-A_i))\leq \mu^*(A_i-B)+\mu^*(B-A_i)$. I need to find an upper bound of this.

The set $B$ contains exactly all elements $x$ that appear in infinitely many $A_i$'s.

I should have $B-A_i\subseteq \bigcup_{k=i+1}^{\infty}(A_k-A_i)$, which yields an upper bound for $\mu^*(B-A_i)$. We have $\mu^*(B-A_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(A_k-A_i)$, but this is an infinite sum, and even though each term is less than $\varepsilon^i$, we still cannot bound it by anything better than infinity. In particular, how can we use the geometric convergence condition?

Comment: Would it help if you'd have shown that $B$ consists of exactly those points $x\in X$ which are elements of infinitely many $A_i$'s?

Comment: @JonathanY. Thanks, I think it helps with finding an upper bound for one side. I still can't get for the other side. (See my edit.)

Comment: Oh, I think the other inclusion holds too!

Comment: Hmm.. I was wrong. That doesn't quite finish the problem.

Comment: It seems to me you've just about got it. The only thing is, to actually have a converging series, try $A_{k+1}\setminus A_k$ and vice versa.

Comment: @JonathanY. Yep, nice move there